# Why HKSample array always have 1 value for a HKAnchoredObjectQuery with no limits,no predicate, no anchor?

Tags: watchos-2, healthkit

I am trying to understand how HKAnchoredObjectQuery works. Once the workout started and workout session state changes to running, I call the following function to execute the query and get the Heart Beat Value.

```
func createHeartRateStreamingQuery() {

   guard let quantityType = HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRate) else { return nil }

    var heartRateQuery : HKAnchoredObjectQuery? = HKAnchoredObjectQuery(type: quantityType, predicate: nil, anchor: nil, limit: Int(HKObjectQueryNoLimit)) { (query, sampleObjects, deletedObjects, newAnchor, error) -> Void in

    }

    heartRateQuery!.updateHandler = {(query, samples, deleteObjects, newAnchor, error) -> Void in
        {
           //Samples only have 1 entry which is the most recent reading.
        }
    }

    self.healthStore.executeQuery(heartRateQuery!)

}
```

HeartRateQuery's update handler is called every 2 to 3 seconds and samples variable in the completion handler is having only 1 reading of the Heart Rate which is the most current reading. Shouldn't it have all the readings of Heart Rate since the workout started since I have not set any limits, predicate or anchor on the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you are seeing is expected. The `updateHandler` is only called with samples that are new since the handler was last invoked. If you want to keep track of the samples recorded during the workout then you should add them to an array each time the handler is called.

Note that because you are not using a predicate, the initial results block will include all heart rate samples that are currently available in HealthKit, not just the samples recorded during the workout session. You should probably constrain the query with a date predicate to only get the samples you are interested in.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that the update handler only returns the recent most entry and the initial result block will include all the heart rate samples. Instead of date, I am now using the anchor that was obtained from the last update handler, to get all the samples that were recorded while the app was suspended